# Having difficulty designing a database with a bidirectional optional 1:1 relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, erd

Let's say you have two entities...cars and spoilers.

A car can either have no spoiler or a maximum of one spoiler.

A spoiler can either be sitting on the shelf or be installed on a single car.

The way the system is going to be designed, spoiler details will be stored first and may or may not be associated with an existing car during its lifetime.

What is the best way to define the relationship between these two tables?

My first thought was to create foreign keys in each table linking to the primary of the other table:

`CARS
CarId
CarDesc
SpoilerId`

`SPOILERS
SpoilerId
SpoilerDesc
CarId`

But I get the feeling that I will run into integrity constraints when I try to delete.

My second thought was to just have a foreign key for spoilers in the CARS table, and if I ever need to retrieve all spoilers on the shelf I can just run something similar to
`SELECT * FROM SPOILERS WHERE SPOILER.SPOILDERID NOT IN (SELECT SPOILERID FROM CARS)`
But wouldn't this mean that I would have to do a full table scan every time I want to find out which spoilers are on the shelf? Can this have an impact on performance if i'm expecting hundreds of thousands of records in each table?

My third thought was to create a convergence table:

`CARS
CarId
CarDesc`

`CARS_SPOILERS
SpoilerId
CarId`

`SPOILERS
SpoilerId
SpoilerDesc`

But wouldn't this leave the possibility of defining multiple spoilers for a car, or vice versa? Should I set CARS_SPOILERS.SpoilerId and CARS_SPOILERS.CarId to be unique?

Is there a better way of doing this other than what was mentioned above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Car table with spoiler reference (id) as a foreign key to a Spoiler table describing the spoiler (not referencing Car).

You can find uninstalled spoilers with (select * from Spoiler where spoilerid not in (select spoilerid from car). IF there is a performance problem, you can index spoilerid in cars.

Simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to defend your last approach, with the "convergence" table (what I would call a junction or association table).

First, you can enforce uniqueness by just requiring that both `CarId` and `SpoilerId` be unique.  It is quite convenient when MySQL can enforce relational constraints without having to resort to triggers.

The main reason, though, is aesthetic.  I'm trying to picture your world of cars and spoilers and shelves.  And then I'm thinking:  "Hmmm, maybe there is more than one shelf."  And if there is, what spoiler does it contain?  Don't I want to have a `Shelves_Spoilers` table so I can answer questions about shelves and their spoilers?

The aesthetic reason is the symmetry `Shelves_Spoilers` and `Cars_Spoilers`.